# How to create a discord bot that only allows a specific word in a certain text channel

Tags: discord

I am trying to create a discord bot that only allows the word "upgrade" in a certain text channel.

As I am very new to this I would like to learn about how this is done.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it a substitute for guides, tutorials, and documentation. Please include your attempt to implement such bot to your question. See also:  [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 2):

Its easy. First create a bot. I guess you know about node.js if not, find tutorials for creating a project with discord.js.

First create a client:

`const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login("SuperSecretBotTokenHere");`

(make sure you have a bot token) [discordapp.com/developers](https://discordapp.com/developers)

Then you create a message event:

`client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.content != "upgrade") return message.delete()
});`

Put your bot in the server, give it permissions to delete messages in the channel aaand done!

Sorry for my bad English.